# "Input is not valid. Should be a string, a list/tuple of strings or a list/tuple of integers." ValueError: Input is not valid

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tokenize, bert-language-model

I am using Bert tokenizer for french and I am getting this error but I do not seems to solutionated it. If you have a suggestion.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "training_cross_data_2.py", line 240, in <module>
    training_data(f, root, testdir, dict_unc)
  File "training_cross_data_2.py", line 107, in training_data
    Xtrain_emb, mdlname = get_flaubert_layer(data)
  File "training_cross_data_2.py", line 40, in get_flaubert_layer
    tokenized = texte.apply((lambda x: flaubert_tokenizer.encode(x, add_special_tokens=True, max_length=512, truncation=True)))
  File "/home/getalp/kelodjoe/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 3848, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 2329, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "training_cross_data_2.py", line 40, in <lambda>
    tokenized = texte.apply((lambda x: flaubert_tokenizer.encode(x, add_special_tokens=True, max_length=512, truncation=True)))
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils.py", line 907, in encode
    **kwargs,
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils.py", line 1021, in encode_plus
    first_ids = get_input_ids(text)
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils.py", line 1003, in get_input_ids
    "Input is not valid. Should be a string, a list/tuple of strings or a list/tuple of integers."
ValueError: Input is not valid. Should be a string, a list/tuple of strings or a list/tuple of integers.
```

I look around to fond answer but whaever is proposed do not seems to work. Texte is  dataframe.

here the code :

```
def get_flaubert_layer(texte): # teste is dataframe which I take from an excel file
    
    language_model_dir= os.path.expanduser(args.language_model_dir)
    lge_size = language_model_dir[16:-1]   # modify when on jean zay 27:-1
    print(lge_size)
    flaubert = FlaubertModel.from_pretrained(language_model_dir)
    flaubert_tokenizer = FlaubertTokenizer.from_pretrained(language_model_dir)
    tokenized = texte.apply((lambda x: flaubert_tokenizer.encode(x, add_special_tokens=True, max_length=512, truncation=True)))
    max_len = 0
    for i in tokenized.values:
        if len(i) > max_len:
            max_len = len(i)
    padded = np.array([i + [0] * (max_len - len(i)) for i in tokenized.values])
    attention_mask = np.where(padded != 0, 1, 0)
```

I have another file of the same structure but it is working but for this case I do not know why I get this error should I redownload the model ?

the file kook like this  :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbFc2.png)

Comment: This question does not appear to be related to Django so I am removing that tag. Please don't add unrelated tags to your question.

Answer (score 2):

The stack track of your error is pretty much self-explanatory.

```
"Input is not valid. Should be a string, a list/tuple of strings or a list/tuple of integers." ValueError: Input is not valid
```

A tokenizer requires some text or list of text to operate on.

Let's say the field `texte` represents a `pandas` dataframe corresponding to your dataset which in turn has a column called `verbatim` that corresponds to the texts that you want to tokenize.

All you have to do is pass this list of text in a 'list' format to the tokenizer and make sure the list does not contain nulls or empty text. Here's how you would do it:

```
texte.dropna(subset=['verbatim'], inplace=True) #drop null text rows
tokenized = flaubert_tokenizer.encode(texte['verbatim'].tolist(), 
    add_special_tokens=True, 
    max_length=512, 
    truncation=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to change this line:

```
tokenized = texte.apply((lambda x: flaubert_tokenizer.encode(x, add_special_tokens=True, max_length=512, truncation=True)))
```

to

```
tokenized = flaubert_tokenizer.encode(texte["verbatim"], 
    add_special_tokens=True, 
    max_length=512, 
    truncation=True)`
```

This has two advantages:

1. You don't pass a pandas row to tokenize function (which I'm guessing is what was causing your error).
2. You're not calling the `encode` function once per row. Which will probably speed up tokenization.

Comment: thank you but i still have the same errors